# What is the user name associated with the Guest Account?

Tags: ssh, leopard, guest-account

I'm trying to clamp down SSH access to a OS X 10.5 machine. Its a PowerMac used for testing software under the PowerPC.

SSH servers have a "Deny" configuration option that allows us to explicitly deny access based on a user. For a defense-in-depth measure, I want to specifically deny Guest access.

I'm having trouble finding information on what the actual user name is for the Guest Account. The *Settings* → *Users & Groups* app does not list it:

[image: Users & Groups app under Settings]

Following [How can I list all user accounts in the terminal?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/29874), the `dscacheutil` command *does not* list the account.

And there is no *`man`* page on it:

```
$ man guest
No manual entry for guest
```

What is the user name associated with the Guest Account?

Comment: Is the guest acct even enabled? It's not checked in your screenshot.   Also read the text about guest under that enable check box, it says users can't use guest remotely which would include ssh.

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way to know Guest user name would be login to the system as guest and in terminal type `id`

My guess is that user name for Guest is guest

Comment: I beginning to think its a noble cause but a moot point. When I added a Deny for Guest,  `sshd_config` failed to validate with a "unknown user" error. I despise it when the god damn window manager, rather than the system and its user database, try to manage users. Nothing good ever comes of it.

Answer (score 1):

According to the info on the Guest user in the Users & Groups panel, it states that Users cannot log into the Guest user remotely.

Additionally, there is this question on SO: [Is there a default SSH password on Mac OS X?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/19522/is-there-a-default-ssh-password-on-mac-os-x), specifically the accepted answer:

> Having no password on the OS level effectively means that ssh is disabled for that user. The protocol insists on a non-zero password and thus the hashes of whatever password is supplied fails to match the absence of a hash.

Comment: From the question: *"For a defense-in-depth measure, I want to specifically deny Guest access."*